# Set timeout value for Urlfetchapp.fetch function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, timeout, urlfetch

I am trying to post a json payload to a url using Urlfetchapp.fetch function and receive a json response for that request.

Sample code:

```
var url = "https://example.com/RST/myapi";
var accessToken = getAccessToken();
var headers = {
  "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken
};
var options = {
  "headers": headers,
  "method" : "POST",
  "contentType" : "application/json",
  "payload" : '{ "Name": "Mark" }',
  "muteHttpExceptions": true
};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```

However, my request get interrupted by timeout error. I am told that due to resource heavy APIs, the request can take upto 3 minutes to return a response depending on server status.

Is there anyway to change the limit of timeout on this? Make it wait at least 3 mins till any response is received?

EDIT: I was just told that the API service doesn't have a callback url argument, however it might respond faster on retrying again. But I am not sure how to do that? Its not a response error which I can catch and examine. But a timeout error which means nothing executes after that

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If the API supports a callback url argument, e.g. a URL to post the result back to, you could create a webapp for your script project and pass its url. You'd need to split your script up to support asynchronous behavior, but for JavaScript that's kinda normal ;) as they know they have a slow API for some requests, they may support such an action.

Comment: @tehhowch thanks for the suggestion. I will take a look into that. I have never done a webapp before but should be easy. If I have issues, hope I can come back here to ask more :)

Comment: I was just told that the API service doesnt have a callback url argument, however it might respond faster on retrying again. But I am not sure how to do that. Its not a response error, but a timeout error which means nothing executes after that.

Comment: You can mute the exception, and check the status code of the request. If it failed, you can requery the endpoint. Alternately, wrap your `.fetch` in a try-catch block.

Comment: Try catch didnt work too and as you can see in my sample code I set _muteHttpExceptions_ to true as well. I also removed any other API calls in same execution. Still getting the same error, _Exception: Timeout: www.example.com_.

Also, it gives timeout exception in exactly one minute, while script is supposed to run for at least 6 mins.

Comment: `try { ...fetch } catch (err) { console.warn('retrying request') /* repeat your fetch call */ }` will still raise an error if you get the timeout when in the catch block. As far as the `muteHttpExceptions` option not silencing a timeout, a timeout is not an HTTP error code, so I was wrong to suggest that it could work ;)

Comment: Look into serializing your current execution state (e.g. PropertiesService / CacheService) and resuming from a saved state (i.e. sending the same query) on the next script execution. You can only store strings and there are size limits for those services, after which you could still use a spreadsheet as data storage (or fusiontables, etc). You'd want to save the query and the consumer of the query data, at minimum.

Comment: Will look into serializing the execution, but I am not sure about that. Anyway, thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

check [GAS Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)

Script runtime is 6 min so it's more then 3 min, If your API response take more then 6 min so GAS will stop the function

Comment: Thanks, I dont think the timeout error comes back after 6 minutes. Its usually way before that, something like 2-5 mins.

Comment: Got the same error. In exactly 1 minute. Looks like `UrlFetchApp` has undocumented unchangeable its own timeout.